# Python: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'x.cfxfe'

Tags: python

I am trying to run a script I created for mojibake fix:

```
from ftfy.fixes import fix_encoding_and_explain
import pymysql.cursors

# Connect to the database
connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                             user='root',
                             password='',
                             db='default',
                             charset='utf8mb4',
                             cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor,
                             autocommit=True)
def fix(string):
    fixed, steps = fix_encoding_and_explain(string)
    return fixed

cursor = connection.cursor()   
cursor.execute("SELECT `id`,`name`,`bio` FROM `archived_profiles_2411` ORDER BY `id` ASC LIMIT 5")
numrows = cursor.rowcount

for x in range(0,numrows):
    row = cursor.fetchone()
  
    sql = "UPDATE `archived_profiles_2411` SET `name` = %s AND `bio` = %s WHERE `id` = %s LIMIT 1"
    cursor.execute(sql, (fix(row['name']), fix(row['bio']), str(row['id'])))
```

Although it throws this at me? I've never had this issue ever while interacting with MySQL.

```
Python: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'x.cfxfe'
```

It seems to be coming from the value for the `name` column. The `name` column is a `varchar(255)`.

Stacktrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "unicode-fixer.py", line 26, in <module>
    cursor.execute(sql, (str(fix(row['name'])), fix(row['bio']), str(row['id'])))
  File "/home/ash/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 163, in execute
    result = self._query(query)
  File "/home/ash/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 321, in _query
    conn.query(q)
  File "/home/ash/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 505, in query
    self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)
  File "/home/ash/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 724, in _read_query_result
    result.read()
  File "/home/ash/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1069, in read
    first_packet = self.connection._read_packet()
  File "/home/ash/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 676, in _read_packet
    packet.raise_for_error()
  File "/home/ash/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/protocol.py", line 223, in raise_for_error
    err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)
  File "/home/ash/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/err.py", line 107, in raise_mysql_exception
    raise errorclass(errno, errval)
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (1292, "Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'x.cfxfe'")
```

Comment: What is that fix function returning?

Comment: @OneCricketeer a string. I've even tried wrapping it in `str()`, still the same issue :(

Comment: I mean, is `x.cfxfe` what you expect it to return? And for the name or the bio field?

Comment: Yes, it is the correct value I expect returned, bio is the same, a string, as expected for the return.

Comment: Could you paste the entire error message? That would help a great deal.

Comment: @RobbytheBelgian I have updated my question :)